# How to get coords of cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any possibility to get the coords of cell that contains a value ?

example: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0ZgQ.png)

in this example the result is "C5"
How to get this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: With Excel or Google sheets?

Comment: @SolarMike google sheets

Comment: Which do you want to achieve your goal using the built-in formulas or Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Tanaike both if it is possible

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer using Google Apps Script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the custom function using Google Apps Script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```
const SAMPLE = text => SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .createTextFinder(text)
  .matchEntireCell(true)
  .findAll()
  .map(r => r ? r.getA1Notation() : "")
  .join(",");
```

- In order to use this, please put a formula of `=SAMPLE("Text1")` to a cell as the custom function. By this, the found cell is returned as the A1Notation.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Answer (score 0):

For a formula, you could try something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(textjoin(",",true,if(A:C=D5,address(row(A:C),column(A:C),4),)))
```

[image]

assuming you want to search columns A to C. If the formula is on the same sheet, you couldn't search the whole sheet because you would get a circular reference error, but you could put it on a different sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula(textjoin(",",true,if(Sheet3!A:Z=A2,address(row(Sheet3!A:Z),column(Sheet3!A:Z),4),)))
```

[image]